# What sheaf topoi classify: attribution request

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, reference-request

Is there an accepted name or attribution by which to refer to the following well-known theorem?

> If C is a small site, then the topos of sheaves on C is the classifying topos for flat cover-preserving functors out of C.

In the case when C has a trivial topology, the corresponding assertion for its presheaf topos is usually called [Diaconescu's theorem](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/Diaconescu%27s+theorem).  But I don't think I have ever seen a name given to the more general version.

Comment: I thought the more general version was also due to Diaconescu, but that might just be because the two versions seem to occupy the same neurons in my head.

Comment: I thought so too, Andreas, but section B3.2 of _Sketches of an Elephant_ and section 4.5 of Borceux's _Handbook of Categorical Algebra 3_ both agree with Mike.  

Answer (score 3):

If the site has finite limits, then this can be found in SGA4 Proposition 4.9.4.

Comment: Exposé IV, of course. :)

Comment: Mais oui! The 4 was for Exposée IV.

Comment: Then you forgot one of the other 4s! It's SGA4, exposé IV, proposition 4.9.4. I do love my SGA4. :)

Comment: Thanks.  But do they give it a name?